# Mongodb: Query with a field value, but also another unknown unique field

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, database, nosql

Lets say my documents are this format(random data):

```
{"_id" : 30, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2312112 "uuid" : 123123123}
{"_id" : 31, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2345112 "uuid" : 123123123}
{"_id" : 32, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2378112 "uuid" : 123123123}
{"_id" : 33, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2378112 "uuid" : 123123123}
{"_id" : 34, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2423112 "uuid" : 123123123}
{"_id" : 35, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2467112 "uuid" : 123123123}
{"_id" : 36, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 127.2312112 "uuid" : 999999999}
{"_id" : 37, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 127.9817112 "uuid" : 999999999}
{"_id" : 38, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 128.2312112 "uuid" : 999999999}
{"_id" : 39, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 128.8312112 "uuid" : 999999999}
```

Lets say this is a trail of a vehicle GPS data.
I need to query mongo. I have only start and end "lat" and "lon" values. For e.g., here for uuid - `123123123`, start values are `"lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2312112` and end values are `"lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2467112`.
But, when I query mongo, I do not want to use the uuid. I want the results of documents, which belong to the same uuid. 
In short, if I have location trail data of multiple vehicles, I need to query with start and end points for a unique vehicle without knowing its uuid.

Comment: What if there are two(or more) vehicles with the same start and end points, but with different routes?

Comment: Get both. For simplicity, to start with, lets assume such case is not there.

Comment: Let's clarify, if you query mongo this way - start: `"lat": 35, "lon" : 119`, end: `"lat": 37, "lon" : 121`, then what result are you expecting?

Comment: @n9code: I am expecting an array of documents which belong to the same  UUID.

Comment: @ spiralarchitect did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). So to get the expected result out of your data, you need to execute an `aggregation pipeline` against it. Here is the solution pipeline for your data. Assuming your collection name is `gps`:

```
db.gps.aggregate([
                    {$match: {
                                lat: {$gte: 36}, 
                                lon: {$gte: 120}, 
                                lat: {$lte: 37}, 
                                lon: {$lte: 130}
                             }
                    },
                    {$group: {_id: '$uuid', data: {$push: 
                                                           {
                                                               _id: '$_id', 
                                                               lat: '$lat', 
                                                               lon: '$lon'
                                                           }
                                                  }
                             }
                    }, 
                    {$project: 
                                {
                                   uuid: '$_id', 
                                   data: 1, 
                                   _id: 0
                                }
                    }
                 ])
```

And here is the result for this example aggregation query:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : 36,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 127.2312112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 37,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 127.9817112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 38,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 128.2312112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 39,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 128.8312112
        }
    ],
    "uuid" : 999999999
}
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : 30,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 120.2312112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 31,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 120.2345112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 32,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 120.2378112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 33,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 120.2378112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 34,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 120.2423112
        },
        {
            "_id" : 35,
            "lat" : 36.1212111,
            "lon" : 120.2467112
        }
    ],
    "uuid" : 123123123
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not find a one-step query to do this. So I've broken it into steps. Please note following points:

1. I've changed the _id field to routeId in my json and queries.
2. The code does not handle asynchronousity. So in the for loop you will need to handle it. Also the count (2) is hardcoded in the loop. You will need to replace it with length of array.
3. I've added three more records in my test so that mutiple uuid's can be tested.

   ```
      {"routeId" : 60, "lat": 36.1212111, "lon" : 120.2312112, 
      "uuid" :44444123},
     {"routeId" : 61,"lat" : 36.8888111,"lon" : 120.9999112,
     "uuid" : 44444123},
       {"routeId" : 63,"lat" : 36.1212111,"lon" : 120.2467112,
     "uuid" : 44444123}
   ```

Finally - here is the code. The first part gets all the distinct uuid's and their respective min and max routeId's for the lat and lon matching.
The second part loops thru and checks if the min and max correspond to the correct UUID and then queries all the data for that UUID. This way if the two pieces of data supplied are in the "middle" - they should be eliminated from final result.

```
var myArray = 
db.stack_30229114.aggregate(
{$match:{uuid : { $in:db.stack_30229114.distinct("uuid", {$or: [
{lat:36.1212111,lon:120.2312112}, {lat:36.1212111,lon:120.2467112}]
})}}},
{ $group: { _id: "$uuid", NrouteId: {$min:"$routeId"}, 
   XrouteId: {$max:"$routeId"}}}
);
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
  minResult = db.stack_30229114.find(
                        {routeId:myArray.result[i].NrouteId,
                        lat:36.1212111,lon:120.2312112}, {uuid:1}
                        );
    maxResult = db.stack_30229114.find(
                        {routeId:myArray.result[i].XrouteId,
                        lat:36.1212111,lon:120.2467112}, {uuid:1}
                        );
 if (minResult.uuid == maxResult.uuid){
        db.stack_30229114.find({uuid:minResult.uuid});
 }  
}
```

Comment: and my collection is called stack_302,...you will need to change that

Comment: thanks pang. Not sure why, I kept getting formatting errors no matter what I tried.